# Display the svg link <title> as a tooltip on keyboard focus?

Tags: svg, tooltip, keyboard-events, onfocus, xlink

Is there a way to get the svg link `<title>` to display as a tooltip on keyboard focus (while pressing Tab)? I could not find any solution to get the tooltips to display. I tried using placing the `<title>` both inside and outside `<text>` but both won't display the tooltip:

```
<a xlink:href="page1.html">
  <text x="608.69202" y="272.89529">
    Page 1
    <title>Page 1</title>
  </text>
</a>

<a xlink:href="page1.html">
  <text x="608.69202" y="272.89529">
    Page 1
  </text>
  <title>Page 1</title>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to display title tooltips programmatically. You would need to create and display your own custom tooltips.